# Firefox for Android Select Element Does Not Drop Down

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

I encountered something very unexpected today in Firefox for Android (Samsung Galaxy Tab S2; Android 6.0.1). HTML `<select>` elements are not dropping down, but instead an overlay-style popup is being displayed. Simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  select {
    height: 3.0em;
    width:15.0em;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="dookie" id="dookie">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox for Android (50.1.0):

[image: Firefox for Android]

Clicking the dropdown produces this:

[image]

Both Chrome for Android and the Android Browser display a dropdown as expected. In Chrome for Android (55.0.2883.91):

[image]

I see nothing in Firefox Settings to alter this behavior. Anyone know why/how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way `firefox` for android display the `select` tag. There is no way  to "fix" this, because it's an operation system behavior.

The only way you can change it and make sure the `select` element behaves exactly the same in all browsers is to use javascript to replace the original `<select>` tag with basic `html` elements (like div/ul/li) and css (which all the regular select libraries does ([select2](https://select2.github.io/), [jquery-ui's selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) and others).

Comment: As demonstrated, this is NOT an operating system behavior: it is specific to Firefox. Chrome, Android, Opera, Opera Mini, Dolphin, Rocket, CM, Fast Browser, etc. - every other android browser I've tested - except Firefox displays select tags according the W3C spec.